# Unable to install perl Crypt::SSLeay on ubuntu

Tags: perl

I have installed openssl library,
but I still fail to install the module.

I get the following output:

```
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lssl32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lssleay32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -leay32
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -llibeay32
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Crypt::SSLeay
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for N/NA/NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/CTX.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/CTX.pm
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/X509.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/X509.pm
cp lib/Net/SSL.pm blib/lib/Net/SSL.pm
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Err.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Err.pm
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Conn.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Conn.pm
cp SSLeay.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay.pm
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Version.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Version.pm
cp lib/Crypt/SSLeay/MainContext.pm blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/MainContext.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Crypt::SSLeay ()
chmod 644 "SSLeay.bs"
"/usr/bin/perl" "/usr/share/perl/5.22/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap "/usr/share/perl/5.22/ExtUtils/typemap" -typemap "typemap"  SSLeay.xs > SSLeay.xsc && mv SSLeay.xsc SSLeay.c
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DDEBIAN -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g   -DVERSION=\"0.72\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.72\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/CORE"   SSLeay.c
SSLeay.xs: In function ‘XS_Crypt__SSLeay__CTX_new’:
SSLeay.xs:152:31: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSLv3_client_method’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_client_method());
                               ^
SSLeay.xs:152:31: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SSL_CTX_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
In file included from SSLeay.xs:35:0:
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1305:17: note: expected ‘const SSL_METHOD * {aka const struct ssl_method_st *}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 __owur SSL_CTX *SSL_CTX_new(const SSL_METHOD *meth);
                 ^
SSLeay.xs:157:31: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSLv2_client_method’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv2_client_method());
                               ^
SSLeay.xs:157:31: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SSL_CTX_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
In file included from SSLeay.xs:35:0:
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1305:17: note: expected ‘const SSL_METHOD * {aka const struct ssl_method_st *}’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 __owur SSL_CTX *SSL_CTX_new(const SSL_METHOD *meth);
                 ^
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc  -shared -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong SSLeay.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so  \
   -lssl -lcrypto -lz   \
  
chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- SSLeay.bs blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.bs 644
Manifying 3 pod documents
  NANIS/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
```

It seems the make procedure works well,
but then the test procedure fails,
the output is as follows:

```
Running make test
Running Mkbootstrap for Crypt::SSLeay ()
chmod 644 "SSLeay.bs"
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00-basic.t ..... 1/? 
#   Failed test 'use Crypt::SSLeay;'
#   at t/00-basic.t line 6.
#     Tried to use 'Crypt::SSLeay'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/home/dcsunset/.cpan/build/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72-eYwzMd/blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so' for module Crypt::SSLeay: /home/dcsunset/.cpan/build/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72-eYwzMd/blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so: undefined symbol: SSLv2_client_method at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/DynaLoader.pm line 187.
#  at t/00-basic.t line 6.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-basic.t line 6.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-basic.t line 6.

#   Failed test 'use Crypt::SSLeay::CTX;'
#   at t/00-basic.t line 7.
#     Tried to use 'Crypt::SSLeay::CTX'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Crypt/SSLeay.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at /home/dcsunset/.cpan/build/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72-eYwzMd/blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/CTX.pm line 2.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-basic.t line 7.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-basic.t line 7.

#   Failed test 'use Crypt::SSLeay::Conn;'
#   at t/00-basic.t line 8.
#     Tried to use 'Crypt::SSLeay::Conn'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Crypt/SSLeay.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at /home/dcsunset/.cpan/build/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72-eYwzMd/blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Conn.pm line 2.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-basic.t line 8.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-basic.t line 8.

#   Failed test 'use Crypt::SSLeay::Err;'
#   at t/00-basic.t line 9.
#     Tried to use 'Crypt::SSLeay::Err'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Crypt/SSLeay.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at /home/dcsunset/.cpan/build/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72-eYwzMd/blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Err.pm line 2.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-basic.t line 9.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-basic.t line 9.

#   Failed test 'use Crypt::SSLeay::MainContext;'
#   at t/00-basic.t line 10.
#     Tried to use 'Crypt::SSLeay::MainContext'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Crypt/SSLeay/CTX.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at /home/dcsunset/.cpan/build/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72-eYwzMd/blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/MainContext.pm line 8.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-basic.t line 10.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-basic.t line 10.

#   Failed test 'use Crypt::SSLeay::Version;'
#   at t/00-basic.t line 12.
#     Tried to use 'Crypt::SSLeay::Version'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Crypt/SSLeay.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at /home/dcsunset/.cpan/build/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72-eYwzMd/blib/lib/Crypt/SSLeay/Version.pm line 2.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-basic.t line 12.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-basic.t line 12.

#   Failed test 'use Net::SSL;'
#   at t/00-basic.t line 23.
#     Tried to use 'Net::SSL'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Crypt/SSLeay.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at /home/dcsunset/.cpan/build/Crypt-SSLeay-0.72-eYwzMd/blib/lib/Net/SSL.pm line 20.
# Compilation failed in require at t/00-basic.t line 23.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00-basic.t line 23.
Undefined subroutine &main::main_ctx called at t/00-basic.t line 49.
# Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 just after 13.
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: You have a fairly modern system. Do not install [Crypt::SSLeay](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay#DO-YOU-NEED-Crypt::SSLeay?). Any programmer who [declares a dependency on Crypt::SSLeay](https://www.nu42.com/2014/04/does-your-code-really-depend-on.html) is doing it wrong. Use `Net::SSLeay` and `IO::Socket::SSL`.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Thanks for your reply. Actually, some existing software depends on that, and I have to install it to run the software.

Comment: I am 99% certain the software you mention only needs to depend on `LWP::Protocol::https` and not `Crypt::SSLeay`. Declaring a dependency on `Crypt::SSLeay` is wrong in almost all cases.

Comment: @SinanÜnür Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: Actually, installing `Crypt::SSLeay` installs `LWP::Protocol::https` which also causes `IO::Socket::SSL` and `Net::SSLeay` to be installed thereby ensuring your code **will not** use `Crypt::SSLeay` **unless** you take specific steps to force its use (which I don't recommend). That is my way of spreading the modern libraries to places where people think they need to declare an explicit dependency on `Crypt::SSLeay`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you want to install this in the system library? Perhaps just use the pre-packaged version.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcrypt-ssleay-perl
```